# C++ concept for argument matching of const/non-const references to specified type on template functions

Tags: c++, constraints, c++20, argument-matching

I want to know if there is a better way to solve the code duplication problem on template functions like this

```
struct Z {
    void doSomething() { std::cout << "non-const version\n"; }
    void doSomething() const { std::cout << "const version\n"; }
};

void tempFunc( Z& z ) {
    z.doSomething(); // calls non-const member function
}
void tempFunc( const Z& z ) {
    z.doSomething(); // calls const member function
}

int main() {
    Z z;
    const Z cz;
    tempFunc(z);
    tempFunc(cz);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, both definitions of tempFunc are the same, so in order to avoid code duplication I rewrote that function under C++20 using constraints like this

```
void tempFunc( std::convertible_to<Z> auto&& z ) {
    z.doSomething();
}
```

Note the use of std::is_convertible_to<> and it works fine, but I suspect that there should be a standard (or if not an easy to write constraint) to use instead of is_convertible_to<> that restricts the argument matching only to const and non-const references.

Comment: Are you interested in classes that inherit from Z? Should those be valid arguments?

Comment: Can you use C++23?

Answer (score 2):

`std::convertible_to` is the wrong concept. You don't want something that is *convertible to* `Z`. You need something that *is a `Z`*.

Or, not specifically is-a, since `Z const` and `Z&&` are both not literally `Z` but you want to allow those too.

For this, typically what people write is:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
concept DecaysTo = std::same_as<std::decay_t<U>, T>;
```

Used as:

```cpp
void tempFunc( DecaysTo<Z> auto&& z ) {
    z.doSomething();
}
```

This now matches any type `T` such that `std::decay_t<T>` is `Z`. Which is `Z [const][&|&&]`, basically. That's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::same_as` to constrain the un-*cvref* type of the deduced type to be `Z`

```
template<class T>
  requires std::same_as<Z, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>
void tempFunc( T&& z ) {
    z.doSomething();
}
```

It is worth noting that member functions of class `Z` can also take advantage of C++23 [Deducing `this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Explicit_object_parameter) to reduce duplication

```
struct Z {
  void doSomething(this auto&& self) { /* */ }
};
```